# Jsoup image tag extraction 

Tags: java, jsoup

i need to extract an image tag using jsoup from this html

```
<div class="picture"> 
    <img src="http://asdasd/aacb.jpgs" title="picture" alt="picture" />
</div>
```

i need to extract the src of this img tag ...
i am using this code i am getting null value

```
Element masthead2 = doc.select("div.picture").first();
String linkText = masthead2.outerHtml();
Document doc1 = Jsoup.parse(linkText);
Element masthead3 = doc1.select("img[src]").first();
String linkText1 = masthead3.html();
```

Comment: Can you post the html to extract from? With your code is not clear how the html is composed.

Comment: this is the html <div class="picture"> 
    <img src="http://asdasd/aacb.jpgs" title="picture" alt="picture" />
</div>

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example to get the image source attribute:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div class=\"picture\"><img src=\"http://asdasd/aacb.jpgs\" title=\"picture\" alt=\"picture\" /></div>");
    Element img = doc.select("div.picture img").first();
    String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
    System.out.println("Img source: " + imgSrc);
}
```

The `div.picture img` selector finds the image element under the div.

The main extract methods on an element are:

- `attr(name)`, which gets the value of an element's attribute,
- `text()`, which gets the text content of an element (e.g.  in `<p>Hello</p>`, text() is "Hello"),
- `html()`, which gets an element's inner HTML (`<div><img></div>` html() = `<img>`), and
- `outerHtml()`, which gets an elements full HTML (`<div><img></div>` html() = `<div><img></div>`)

You don't need to reparse the HTML like in your current example, either select the correct element in the first place using a more specific selector, or hit the `element.select(string)` method to winnow down.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code I can extract the image correctly:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<div class=\"picture\"> <img src=\"http://asdasd/aacb.jpgs\" title=\"picture\" alt=\"picture\" /> </div>");

    Element elem = doc.select("div.picture img").first();

    System.out.println("elem: " + elem.attr("src"));
```

I'm using jsoup release **1.2.2**, the latest one.

Maybe you're trying to print the inner html of an empty tag like img.

From the documentation: "html() - Retrieves the element's inner HTML".

For the second portion of html you can use:

```
    Document doc2 = Jsoup.parse("<tr>  <td class=\"blackNoLine\" nowrap=\"nowrap\" valign=\"top\" width=\"25\" align=\"left\"><b>CAST: </b></td>  <td class=\"blackNoLine\" valign=\"top\" width=\"416\">Jay, Shazahn Padamsee&nbsp;</td>  </tr>");
    Elements trElems = doc2.select("tr");
    if (trElems != null) {
        for (Element element : trElems) {
            Element secondTd = element.select("td").get(1);

            System.out.println("name: " + secondTd.text());
        }
    }
```

which prints "Jay, Shazahn Padamsee".

Comment: ya thanks yar another one ..  <dt>Size:</dt>
  <dd>example text</dd>

  <br />
 it have a lot of dd and dt how can i extract the exact one

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? Can you post also the html code of the request?

Comment: how can i extract the second element in an class 
  <tr>
       <td class="blackNoLine" nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" width="25" align="left"><b>CAST: </b></td>
       <td class="blackNoLine" valign="top" width="416">Jay, Shazahn Padamsee&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

i need to extract Jay, Shazahn Padamsee&nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>  <td class="blackNoLine" nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" width="25" align="left"><b>CAST: </b></td>  <td class="blackNoLine" valign="top" width="416">Jay, Shazahn Padamsee&nbsp;</td>  </tr>
```

You can use:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(...);
Elements els = doc.select("td[class=blackNoLine]");
Element el= els.get(1);
String castName = el.text();
```