# JSOUP - Crawling Images & Text from URLs Found on a Previously Crawled Page

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm attempting to create a crawler using Jsoup that will...

1. Go to a web page (specifically, a google sheets publicly published page like this one https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CE9HTe2rdgPsxMHj-PxoKRGX_YEOCRjBTIOVtLa_2iI/pubhtml) and collect all href url links found in each cell.
2. Next, I want it to go to each individual url found the page, and crawl THAT url's headline and main image.
3. Ideally, if the urls on the google sheets page were for example, a specific Wikipedia page and a Huffington Post article, it would print out something like:

> 1. Link: https: //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D 
>      Headline: Wolfenstein 3D 
>      Image: https: //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D#/media/File:Wolfenstein-3d.jpg
> 2. Link: http: //www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/01/02/ron-pippin_n_1180149.html 
>      Headline: Ron Pippin’s Mythical Archives Contain History Of Everything (PHOTOS) 
>      Image: http: //i.huffpost.com/gen/453302/PIPPIN.jpg
>
>    > (excuse the spaces in the URLs. Obviously I don't want the crawler to add spaces and break up URLS... stack overflow just wouldn't let me post more links in this question)

So far, I've got the jsoup working for the first step (pulling the links from the initial url) using this code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class mycrawler {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CE9HTe2rdgPsxMHj-PxoKRGX_YEOCRjBTIOVtLa_2iI/pubhtml").get();
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {          
                    System.out.println(link.text());
            }
       } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm now having trouble figuring out how to create the second aspect of the crawler where it cycles through each link (could be a variable number of links) and finds the headline and main image from each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc;
    String url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CE9HTe2rdgPsxMHj-PxoKRGX_YEOCRjBTIOVtLa_2iI/pubhtml";
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            String innerurl = link.text();

            if (!innerurl.contains("://")) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("*******");
            System.out.println(innerurl);

            Document innerDoc = Jsoup.connect(innerurl).get();
            Elements headerLinks = innerDoc.select("h1");
            for (Element innerLink : headerLinks) {
                System.out.println("Headline : " + innerLink.text());
            }

            Elements imgLinks = innerDoc.select("img[src]");
            for (Element innerLink : imgLinks) {
                String innerImgSrc = innerLink.attr("src");

                if(innerurl.contains("huffingtonpost") && innerImgSrc.contains("i.huffpost.com/gen")){                      
                    System.out.println("Image : " + innerImgSrc);
                }
                if(innerurl.contains("wikipedia")) {

                    Pattern pattern =   Pattern.compile("(jpg)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                    Matcher matcher =   pattern.matcher(innerImgSrc);
                    if(matcher.find()){
                        System.out.println("Image : " + innerImgSrc);
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

`Output`

```
*******
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D
Headline : Wolfenstein 3D
Image : //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/05/Wolfenstein-3d.jpg
*******
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/01/02/ron-pippin_n_1180149.html
Headline : Ron Pippin's Mythical Archives Contain History Of Everything (PHOTOS)
Image : http://i.huffpost.com/gen/453302/PIPPIN.jpg
Image : http://i.huffpost.com/gen/453304/PIPSHIP.jpg
```

Comment: Hey Devendra! Thanks for this it works great with some tweaking! Obviously I can't do a general rule for everything, and will have to make additional rules for other websites besides huffington post and wikipedia that may appear in the spreadsheet (right?). How would you specify something like "for all articles from ____ website, choose the second image that matches the criteria"? What would you do if the image URL from a particular website was buried in a div class instead of an img src?

Comment: @TylerSobel-Mason, you might want to do something like `Element img = doc.select("div.picture img").first();`. Refer this [SO ans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391422/jsoup-image-tag-extraction)

Comment: Hey Devendra - One last question if you don't mind - I've been trying what you said above about `.first().` It's not really working because it pulls the first image it finds, and then checks only that image for the pattern within the if statement. Is there a way to return the first response of what it finds **after** it runs the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the `href` attribute of the link with `link.attr("href")` instead of  `link.text()`. (in the page the displayed text and the underlying href are different) Track all the links to a list and iterate that list in second step to get the corresponding `Document` from which you can extract the Headline and Image URL.

For wiki pages we can extract the heading with `Jsoup` as follows

```
Element heading = document.select("#firstHeading").first();
System.out.println("Heading : " + heading.text());
```